# Choosing between multiple classes efficiently

Tags: ios, swift

Writing UI programmatically I am having this problem every time again.

A user presses a button, and according to the data, I have to choose what window to open, where each window is a custom class (`UIView`).

If I have to choose between 10 options I get this :

```
                   if ( name == "option1" ) {
                    let Picker1:PortsPicker1 = PortsPickerView(frame:WindowsRect)
                    Picker1.delegate=self
                    Picker1.setWithPorts(ports: blockData["PORTS"] as! [String], selectedPorts: ["1"])
                    self.view.addSubview(Picker1) 
                    }
                   if( option 2 .... ){...}
```

Then consider having 10 like this where every option is a different class view to show.

Usually, you do this logic with variables with one line, but since a class name is not a variable you can't do something like `array[name]'.

What would be a good way to return a kind of class (`Picker1,Picker2`) according to some condition so **I will not have to rewrite** all these lines (e.g `picker1.delegate=self`)

Comment: Why dont you just make 1 `Picker` class that handle all the options? Since by your requirement they look pretty the same, just change the data of it

Comment: Not sure I understand you .. a single class that runs over all the options with conditions ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass option1, option2,... to that class and it will change the looks and data if it have almost similar looks

Comment: Because every picker visually looks completely different .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming that you Picker views have the same property and methods*, you have multiple solutions:

**Base class**: you can create a base class, that will have the common properties, and let Picker views to extend it.
Your code will become something like that:

```
var picker: PortsPicker? = nil
if ( name == "option1" ) {
    picker = PortsPickerViewOne(frame:WindowsRect)
else if ( name == "option2" ) {
    picker = PortsPickerViewTwo(frame:WindowsRect)
} else {
    // Other code for not handled options
}

if let pickerView = picker {
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.setWithPorts(ports: blockData["PORTS"] as! [String], selectedPorts: ["1"])
    self.view.addSubview(pickerView) 
}
```

**Protocol**: it is a similar approach to the previous one, you can create a base protocol for your pickers so all of them will have the properties/methods you need:

```
var picker: PortsPickerProtocol? = nil
if ( name == "option1" ) {
    picker = PortsPickerViewOne(frame:WindowsRect)
else if ( name == "option2" ) {
    picker = PortsPickerViewTwo(frame:WindowsRect)
} else {
    // Other code for not handled options
}

if let pickerView = picker {
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.setWithPorts(ports: blockData["PORTS"] as! [String], selectedPorts: ["1"])
    self.view.addSubview(pickerView) 
}
```

Based on these options, there are some ways to improve the code:

- The option become a enumeration, so you can avoid copy/paste and typing mistakes
- Once you have an enumeration, you can move the creation in a different component, creating a Factory. It will become something like:

  class PickerFactory {

  ```
  pickerForValue(value: OptionEnum) -> PortsPicker? {
      switch(value) {
      case OptionPicker1:
          return PortsPickerViewOne
      case OptionPicker2:
          return PortsPickerViewTwo
      }

      return nil
  }
  ```

  }

Your code (took from example **Base class**) become something like:

```
if let pickerView = PickerFactory().pickerForValue("option1") {
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.setWithPorts(ports: blockData["PORTS"] as! [String], selectedPorts: ["1"])
    self.view.addSubview(pickerView) 
}
```

Much cleaner and safe from copy/paste or typing mistakes.

The factory is also very useful in case of different methods/properties, in the switch you canperform what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but how in your very last code paragraph are you going to have access to pickerView.delegate ? the factory returns PortsPicker which in compile time the system doesn't really "see" as the original class with its members - so I will get an error that no such delegate method is in pickerView  ( ? )

Comment: Hi curnelius, if the PortsPicker - which is the base class - has a delegate property, all the classes that extend it have it too, so you won't have any problem since delegate will be part part of the Picker.